# How to time duration calculate in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to calculate the time duration with the current time and another time. In my problem the current time and all ready time in data base time format are different, this format is given format: 2020-11-07 , 22:52
but now time format is `30/10/2020 , 20:50:34` . So I have a problem with this diffrent format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert both values to timestamps (in milliseconds) from their own formats and then calculate the difference in milliseconds with simple math.

If you are having trouble parsing the values, you can check [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) documentation. An example can be:

```
let birthday = new Date('1995-12-17T03:24:00')
```